# Wait until new data is detected in Firebase database (web)

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In this example I want to change of site when a new node called "friend" is created in a parent node in the firebase database. I don't know how to make it wait until it detects the new node.

```
    var friendUid;
    firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('friend').on('value', function(snapshot){
       friendUid = snapshot.val();
    })
    while(!friendUid){ //I've also tried with "friendUid == null"
     firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('friend').on('value', function(snapshot){
       friendUid = snapshot.val();
     })
    }
    window.document.location = "whatever.html";
```

Comment: What's wrong with the code you have now? Your listeners should be invoked when the data at the given location is first available, and every time it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a loop, but you **do** need to move the code that changes the location *into* the listener:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('friend').on('value', function(snapshot){
  var friendUid = snapshot.val();
  if (friendUid == "what you're looking for") {
    window.document.location = "whatever.html";
  }
})
```

---

If you just want to check if the node exists, that can be simplified to:

```
firebase.database().ref('users/' + uid).child('friend').on('value', function(snapshot){
  if (snapshot.exists()) {
    window.document.location = "whatever.html";
  }
})
```